# How to rewrite this Dictionary For Loop in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a Dictionary of Classes where the classes hold attributes that are lists of strings.

I made this function to find out the max number of items are in one of those lists for a particular person.

```
def find_max_var_amt(some_person) #pass in a patient id number, get back their max number of variables for a type of variable
    max_vars=0
    for key, value in patients[some_person].__dict__.items():
        challenger=len(value)
        if max_vars < challenger:
            max_vars= challenger
    return max_vars
```

What I want to do is rewrite it so that I do not have to use the .iteritems() function. This `find_max_var_amt` function works fine as is, but I am converting my code from using a dictionary to be a database using the dbm module, so typical dictionary functions will no longer work for me even though the syntax for assigning and accessing the key:value pairs will be the same. Thanks for your help!

Comment: AH! My eyes...should...fix...the identations. (makes it kinda hard to read)

Comment: Maybe the gurus know from what you give, but better would be some example data to get your code running and see it in action. Must say that I find your code strange, but I am not yet wedded into class dict mangling. I find it strange that you pass in id_number not object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dbm` doesn't let you iterate over the values directly, you can iterate over the keys. To do so, you could modify your `for` loop to look like

```
for key in patients[some_person].__dict__:
    value = patients[some_person].__dict__[key]
    # then continue as before
```

I think a bigger issue, though, will be the fact that `dbm` only stores strings. So you won't be able to store the list directly in the database; you'll have to store a string representation of it. And that means that when you try to compute the length of the list, it won't be as simple as `len(value)`; you'll have to develop some code to figure out the length of the list based on whatever string representation you use. It could just be as simple as `len(the_string.split(','))`, just be aware that you have to do it.

By the way, your existing function could be rewritten using a generator, like so:

```
def find_max_var_amt(some_person):
    return max(len(value) for value in patients[some_person].__dict__.itervalues())
```

and if you did it that way, the change to iterating over keys would look like

```
def find_max_var_amt(some_person):
    dct = patients[some_person].__dict__
    return max(len(dct[key]) for key in dct)
```

Comment: neater to use `vars(patients[some_person])` than `__dict__`